# How to add a button to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a card Object which looks like this

```
class Card{

    constructor(months,chargeType,paymentType,rates,productType,validStart,validEnd,supplierId){
      this.months = months;
      this.chargeType = chargeType;
      this.paymentType= paymentType;
      this.rates = rates;
      this.productType = productType;
      this.validStart= validStart;
      this.validEnd=validEnd;
      this.supplierId = supplierId;
    }

  }

  class Rate {
    constructor(rate,unit,description){
      this.rate =rate;
      this.unit =unit;
      this.description =description;
    }
  }
```

And I define it like this

```
gblcard = new Card();
gblcard.months = 12;
gblcard.chargeType = 'standard charge';
gblcard.paymentType = 'credit card';
gblcard.productType = 'gas';
gblcard.validEnd = '2017-04-26';
gblcard.validStart ='2017-01-12';
gblcard.supplierId = 23;
gblcard.rates = new Rate(12.74,'mts/h','day') ;
```

The card looks like this

[image]

Now I have that green color eye button on clicking of that i want to open a model which should show some of the Card Details , like supplierId ValidStart , End etc.

My question is how should I assign a click event to the button inside that `Card Object` itself like a property ? and it should pass the relevant property to the `BootStrap modal`

I am trying to learn OOP js .Pardon fo the silly question

Comment: Could you edit this with a part where you actually add the green color eye button? Or its automatically added as a Card object? If so, you have to dig in the object and edit the button there

Comment: @masterfan actually I am creating the card layout in seperate function , Like looping over the cardList  and attaching Html to the dom

Comment: Create a function to load the Card Details model, and pass it to that separate function. Or better say to button on click

Comment: to get help quickly please put all your code on jsfiddle